# View a deleted row in a sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite

I deleted a few rows by accident. Is there something that exist to view/dump recently deleted sqlite rows? I should have made a back up

Answer (score 0):

[undark](http://pldaniels.com/undark/) seems to do the job, assuming you haven't made any maintenance operations in the database.

A little off-topic, but if you're using Linux, you may want to take a look at [storeBackup](http://storebackup.org/) to do some backups next time :)